# Python 3.1 code and error

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

64-bit VISTA
Python 3.1

```
from urllib import request
a = request.urlopen('http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/currency/CUR_USDYEN').read(20500)
b = a[19000:20500]
idx_pricewrap = b.find('pricewrap')
context = b[idx_pricewrap:idx_pricewrap+80]
idx_bgLast = context.find('bgLast')
rate = context[idx_bgLast+8:idx_bgLast+15]
print(rate)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\P31Working\test_urllib.py", line 4, in 
   idx_pricewrap = b.find('pricewrap')
TypeError: expected an object with the buffer interface
Process terminated with an exit code of 1
```

I have NO idea what that error means.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 is a lot more strict when it comes to the difference between bytes and (Unicode) strings. The result of `urlopen(...).read(...)` is of course an object of type `bytes`, and the implementation of `bytes.find` doesn't allow you to search for Unicode strings. In your case, you can simply replace "pricewrap" by a binary string:

```
idx_pricewrap = b.find(b'pricewrap')
```

Same applies to other `.find` calls. Python 2 encoded Unicode strings automatically where it made (less or more) sense, but Python 3 has introduced more restrictions that you need to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks very much. Before I saw your answer I found a relevant example in the docs, which I think does what you suggest in a different way. I'll answer my own question to show this.

Comment: @NotSuper: Yes, decoding the website to a Unicode object is a good solution as well. Actually it's the better solution, but for HTML sites you might rather want to use a parser library that can detect the charset automatically (from the HTTP header or the charset definition inside the HTML, instead of assuming UTF-8).

Comment: I'd like to learn how to use a parser library. Could you point me to some examples? I assume I could do this with what 3.1 has?

Comment: @NotSuper: There's a well-known library called [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to do just that. It has a version compatible with Python 3.1. As of the documentation, it automatically produces Unicode strings from HTML input, but I don't know how you can pass the "Content-Type" header to it in case the HTML itself doesn't declare the charset. I haven't used it myself but there are a lot of questions about it on SO so you can get help here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a relevant example in the docs:

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib#examples

The first example gave me some understanding and led me to revising my code to

http://tutoree7.pastebin.com/sUq8s4wh

which works like a charm.